# Compiling multiple versions of a function with different preprocessor variable values

Tags: c++, openmp, preprocessor

I have the following function which uses OpenMP for parallelism:

```
Real3 MyThing::compute(...) {
   // Do some setup...

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(OMP_THREADS)
    {
        // Local variables...
#pragma omp for nowait
        for (...) { ... }
#pragma omp critical
        { ... }
    }

    // Wrap up and return
}
```

Where the number of threads used can be determined at compile time by the `OMP_THREADS` preprocessor variable.

Because the problem size is determined in configuration files, it is only known at runtime. So, I would like to compile this function for multiple values of `OMP_THREADS` (and one without OMP at all), and then have a runtime condition to decide which version to run, e.g.:

```
if (mode == "ompx4") {
    return compute_omp4(...);
} else if (mode == "ompx8") {
    return compute_omp8(...);
} else {
    return compute_serial(...);
}
```

Obviously I could do this by just copy-pasting the entire function multiple times and hard-coding a different value of `OMP_THREADS` in each, but since this is a fairly large function, that's not ideal.

Normally I'd do something like with with template variables, but I don't think I can set the `num_threads` like that. Any suggestions on how to make this in a reasonably compact form?

Comment: Platform?  MSVC has `_pragma` but I don't know if it would work here

Comment: What is the reason to specify the number of threads at compile time? Why not simply let it be decided by `OMP_NUM_THREADS` at runtime and have only a single function that will work with any number of threads? Anyway, you can use a (non-type) template parameter as an "argument" for `num_threads` in `pragma parallel` as well.

Comment: What would be wrong in passing the desired number of threads as an argument of a unique `compute()` function, and use it in the `NUM_THREADS()` clause ?

Comment: @PaulSanders Linux, compiling with GCC

Comment: @DanielLangr for this particular module, depending on the problem size, using as many threads as OMP wants is often not optimal (i.e. it uses too many, resulting in slowdowns rather than speedups). So far I've been imposing 4 threads, but I would like the user to be able to set the number of threads at runtime. And the OMP_NUM_THREADS env var is not an option in this case (there are other modules that may need more threads than this one).

Comment: @DanielLangr I need to try setting the num_threads clause from a template variable, I thought that wouldn't work because #pragma is expanded at the preprocessor stage?

Comment: @SeanBone You're right about preprocessor here, it would likely not work. But as you write, `num_threads` accepts a runtime value as well. If you want to let users to control the number of thread independently of `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, you can also create a separate environment variable for it. It is a common solution in practice. For instance, OpenBLAS has `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `num_threads` clause can be set with a runtime value as well. For some reason I had it in my head it had to be set at compile time.

Thank you to those who helped me out in the comments!